# CSS Responsive Shape Issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, shapes, css-shapes

I added a fixed top search and social bar to my website and all looks fantastic on desktop. It should be responsive, however, I'm having a problem on mobile viewing (tablets/phones, etc.) where it's losing its shape.

The bar itself works great, as does the search part. It's the social css part that's causing the shape to fail on mobile viewing.

Here's what it should look like:
[image: desktopview]

Here's how it looks on mobile:
[image: mobileview]

Here's the coding:

```
.topbar .social {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-bottom: -60px;
}
.topbar .social a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 34px;
    height: 60px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f293b5;
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.topbar .social a:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0; 
    border: solid transparent;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-bottom: 13px solid #fff;
    border-left: 17px solid transparent;
    border-right: 17px solid transparent;
}
```

All code and HTML can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/20tL16v3/
*(ignore the additional Wordpress extras, such as it showing the widget extras.)*

This is driving me crazy! Can anyone help me correct this, or point me in the direction of where I may be going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would really help if you could set this up on jsfiddle for me.

Comment: Could you include your HTML above also?

Comment: looks like its a problem with z-index

Comment: @Larz - Trying to add the HTML here and keeps stating that it's too long in characters, but you can find it in the source coding [here](http://www.sweet2eatbaking.com).

Comment: @jan199674 - Any suggestions on changing that? The topbar css is fixed and has a z-index set.

Comment: @chdltest - Is this what you're looking for? I've included all the css for the entire .topbar, including the separate search and social classes.

The HTML I grabbed from the source code. It's from a Wordpress blog so ignore the additional text-widget classes. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, you gave me what I needed to fix it for you. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a media query that sets your header's overflow to hidden.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1139px) {
  .site-inner, .wrap {
    max-width: 960px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```

Set that to `overflow: visible;` and you should see your ribbons the way you want them to be seen as when you shrink your window.

In the event where you can't find that media query, just set this somewhere in your css if you're desperate: `.site-inner, .wrap { overflow: visible !important; }`

Comment: I was just about to ask whether it was something to do with the media queries! :)

Thank you so, so much, it has fixed the issue. Hurrah.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

`.topbar .social {
    float: right;
    overflow:hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-bottom: -60px;
}`

Also make sure you have viewport metatags in use - you can find more with a quick search.

I hope this helped, - let me know.
Cheers.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. However, adding the overflow hasn't fixed the issue.